# How can I enter Romaji on my Mac keyboard

Tags: discussion

I followed the instructions. Went to System Preferences, added everything and I have a Flag at the top of my screen which I can click to give me US, Romaji, Hiragan and Katakana.

I would like to enter for example Biru where the "I" is long.

I select the Romaji keyboard but I do not know how to enter the long "I" vowel. Is this possible? Right now it seems like the US keyboard and the Romaji keyboard selections act just the same.

Comment: Do you mean the long vowel sign "ー"? If so, press hyphen.

Comment: Maybe he means 'i' but instead of having a dot above, it's a dash.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a long 'i', hold the key down for longer.

No, really. I'm serious. [Holding down the key for longer triggers the accented character input menu](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201586), allowing you to enter the [macron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron). (Note that for this to work, key repeat cannot be set to 'Off' under System Preferences > Keyboard.)

It's also worth noting that the romaji layout is essentially a straight copy of the underlying layout, and personally I find it to be of limited usefulness. What I personally do is to *just* enable the hiragana input mode, and switch languages entirely to enter the Japanese IME, but your mileage may vary (I have Command-Space configured in system preferences to switch input languages, relegating Spotlight to Ctrl-Space, but again, YMMV.)

Comment: IIRC you also need a special setting turned on to do this, otherwise it'll just keep typing a bunch of i.

Comment: @Blavius: Indeed. It's covered in the linked help article, but I'll edit it in.